# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transition') - Swiper & VueJS & Ionic

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5

I can't use the Swiper `slideNext` function in VueJS with Ionic.

I tried the demo codes from the official Swiper website, without success...

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
  <ion-page>
    ...

        <ion-row class="mainRow">
          <ion-col size="12">
            <ion-row>
              <div class="swiper">
                <div
                  class="swiper-slide"
                  v-for="(question, index) in qst"
                  :key="`question_${index}`"
                >
                  ...
  </ion-page>
</template>
<script>

  setup() {
    const swiperRef = ref(null);
    const [slideSpace, setSlideSpace] = useState(0);

    const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
      speed: 400,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: slideSpace,
      controller: {
        control: swiperRef,
      },
      on: {
        slideChange: function (e) {
          setCurrentQuestion(e.activeIndex + 1);
        },
      },
    });

const handleAnswerClick = (event, answer, question) => {

      ...

      setTimeout(() => {
        isCorrect && setScore((score) => score + 1);
        event.target.setAttribute("color", "light");
        swiper.slideNext(); // this line is problematic
        checkIfComplete();
      }, 1000);
    };
```

The error :
[it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7seY.png) comes from the Swiper module

Comment: Looks like the `swiper` element isn't present at the time of initialization, hence is undefined. Take a look at the [Vue Lifecycle Hooks](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html) to see when to call this function properly.